# ios 6 UILocalNotification

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have implemented UILocalNotification for iOS 6 but every time the notification is launched, it is displayed as a banner. Is there way I can default it to be an alert (like previous iOS 4)?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: I think this is a setting which you cannot set programmatically. All apps that use notifications have a setting in the Settings app which you can choose from alert, banner, or none.

Comment: @iBradApps Thanks for the quick response. If you are right then that isn't a very user friendly option. Perhaps they have changed this with ios 6? Maybe someone can confirm this?

Comment: I have not heard of a change.

Comment: @iBradApps if someone would post that as answer, I will gladly accept

Comment: @tc. If someone will post that as answer, I will gladly accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a setting which you cannot set programmatically. All apps that use notifications have a setting in the Settings app which you can choose from alert, banner, or none.

So bottom line, it is up to the user to select the type of notification.